$2017$ primes numbers $p_1,p_2,...,p_{2017}$ are given. Prove that $\prod_{i<j} ({p_i}^{p_j}-{p_j}^{p_i})$ is divisible by $5777$.
$2017$ primes numbers $p_1,p_2,...,p_{2017}$ are given. Prove that $\prod_{i<j} ({p_i}^{p_j}-{p_j}^{p_i})$ is divisible by $5777$.
Here's my attempt to attack this problem.
$5777=53\times109$ and for $5777$ to divide the given product either each of 53 and 109 will divide a term each or both will divide a single term in the product.
WLOG consider two primes $p_i,p_j>109$ ( to ensure that none of those appears in the reduced residue classes of both $53$ and $109$, otherwise they need to both be coprime to 52 and 108) $i\neq j$.
53 being a prime, we know it has a primitive root denoted $g$ such that \begin{cases}p_i\equiv g^{k_1}(mod \ 53) \\ p_j \equiv g^{k_2} (mod\ 53)\end{cases}
implying that \begin{cases}{p_i}^{p_j}\equiv (g^{k_1})^{p_j}(mod \ 53) \\ {p_j}^{p_i} \equiv (g^{k_2})^{p_i} (mod\ 53)\end{cases}  for some distinct $k_1,k_2 \in \{1,2,...,52\}$.
By CRT, we know that there exist a positive integer $x$ such that \begin{cases}x\equiv52·{k_2}^{-1} (mod\ p_j)\\x\equiv52·{k_1}^{-1} (mod\ p_i)\end{cases}
implying that \begin{cases}x·{k_2} \equiv52\ (mod\ p_j)\\x·{k_1}\equiv52\ (mod\ p_i)\end{cases}.
Thus we have   \begin{cases}x·{k_2}=52 +{p_j}·m\\x·{k_1}=52+{p_i}·n\end{cases} for some positive integer m and n. WLOG let $m=n=1$ such that  \begin{cases}x·{k_2}=52 +{p_j}\\x·{k_1}=52+{p_i}\end{cases}
Giving us the following congruence  \begin{cases}x·{k_2}\equiv{p_j}\ (mod\ 52)\\x·{k_1}\equiv{p_i}\ (mod\ 52)\end{cases}.
With this we obtain  \begin{cases}{p_i}^{p_j}\equiv (g^{k_1})^{x·k_2}(mod \ 53) \\ {p_j}^{p_i} \equiv (g^{k_2})^{x·k_1} (mod\ 53)\end{cases}.
Hence $${p_i}^{p_j}-{p_j}^{p_i}\equiv g^{x·k_1·k_2}-g^{x·k_1·k_2}\equiv0\ (mod\ 53)$$. Applying the same reasoning with $109$ we get that $5777|\prod_{i<j} ({p_i}^{p_j}-{p_j}^{p_i})$
Note:I have looked forward to other solutions since it had already be asked few  years ago and i was kind of surprised and confused by the use of PHP meanwhile the fact we dealing with primes suggests to us that they may be gaps that could just not be able of being filled even when using the PHP. except if i missed something in the different demonstrations, i really not understand that PHP approach.

It may be worth pointing out that $5777$ is in fact one of the two known composite Stern numbers: an odd number which can not be represented in the form $2 a^2 + p$ where $a$ is a positive integer and $p$ is a prime. That may or may not help, but I thought I'd mention it as $5777$ has that unusual property and the question may have been crafted with that in mind, so as to be able to exploit it. You'd need to do some work on this, it's beyond my powers, which are dwindling with age.

Incidentally, what do you mean by the PHP?

@Prime Mover
thank you so much man, i have been wondering why did they specifically take 5777 and another one that may seem more natural to come in mind

@Prime Mover
PHP=pigeonhole principle

Welcome to Math SE. FYI, I found the duplicate using an Approach0 search. There's also the AoPS thread Differences of Powers of Primes p^q-q^p, which says the source is Israeli Oral Olympiad #$3$. Finally, after a fairly brief look through your question, note with your $x\cdot k_2=52+p_j\cdot m$ & $x\cdot k_1=52+p_i\cdot n$ for any positive integers, it should be some instead.

@John Omielan
thanks for the remark John.
what's FYI please?

You're welcome. FYI means "For Your Information".
